# What is the best strategy to override a default value in a REST parameter?

Tags: rest

I work on a GET REST API in which a query string parameter may be configured to have a default value if not provided. For example, if the parameter name is `active` and the possible values are `true` and `false`, the administrator of the API has two options:

Option 1: They can specify a default value for `active` such that a request which lacks an `active` parameter assumes the default value. For instance, if the default value is `true` then requesting `www.example.com/api` is identical to `www.example.com/api?active=true`.

Option 2: They can *not* specify a default value for `active` such that `www.example.com/api` means "active-ness" has no effect on the API return. Of course, the client may request `active=true` or `active=false` if they see fit.

Now the requirement is that in an Option 1 configuration, the client should be able to specify they want to negate the default value and make the API behave as if it were configured like Option 2.

So the requirement is:

| Request | Behavior |
| --- | --- |
| www.example.com/api | `active` understood to be the configured default, `true` |
| www.example.com/api?active=true | `active` understood to be `true` |
| www.example.com/api?active=false | `active` understood to be `false` |
| www.example.com/api?[something] | `active` not considered |

In order to implement the last row, I considered passing some special value like `active=none`, but the API is good about validating input types, and I'm reluctant to pollute the semantics with an invalid value.

My best idea is that the empty String, `www.example.com/api?active=` is the best idea. Whether or not the deployed API is configured with Option 1 or 2, the empty String means "'active-ness should not effect the returned results".

Has anyone else faced a similar problem? Do you have a better idea?